# Textarea in gridview showing old values before saving and binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have a GridView which consists of Textbox in each row and its textmode property is set to 'Multiline'.

Whenever I edit the Textbox and click Save button, the edited **Textbox in gridview shows the old values for a second**, gets saved in database **and binds the new value**.

The **GridView** is **enclosed in an UpdatePanel** and also its **ViewState property** is set to **false**. 
Binding is done only after saving the records.

I don't know where it is going wrong.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it has something to do with when your databinding.

Try setting the viewstate back to true, then databind your gridview on

1) !Page.IsPostback 
2) After you have finished the save operation

Comment: If i change the TextMode property to 'Singleline', it works perfectly.

But it doesn't work when I change the same property to 'Multiline'.